# How to use html tags in Android TextView to create tweet interface?

Tags: android, twitter, textview

I want to create a view like the one explained on (guidelines) https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements

I want to do something like:

`textView.setText("<a href=\"....twitter.com/user=abc\">@abc</a> how are you doing <a href=\"...twitter/tag=today\">#today</a>?");`

So, I want to show a basic text, where some words should be clickable to call (if possible a java function and/or) directly open that url in the browser.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your string.xml file define a resource,

```
<string name="tweet"><a href=\"....twitter.com/user=abc\">@abc</a> how are you doing <a href=\"...twitter/tag=today\">#today</a>?</string>
```

Now use,

textView.setText(getResource().getString(R.string.tweet));

Comment: How can I do this dynamically? (As I will be loading tweets from twitter dynamically)

Comment: Then Use Html.fromHtml(String source) method.

Comment: Thank you, can i call a java method with that?

Comment: If the method returns String, you can. All the best

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the WebView class 
[Android SDK WebView Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: I am using custom views to show many tweets in a ListView. So it means that I have to use up to 10 webviews on the same screen (if the screen height is long enough). Thay may not be good for performance?

Comment: Yes. But if it is only for hyperlink you should fetch them and turn them into View which send Intent when you click on it (Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));)